# Notification with action for smartwatch

Tags: java, android, notifications, wear-os

I'm trying to add special actions to a notification such that I can use my smartwatch to remote control the app.

That's my current code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setContentTitle("Control Notification");
builder.setContentText("With this notification I should be able to control the app with my watch.");
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Intent actionIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
actionIntent.putExtra("action", true);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, actionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "action", resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

The problem is that each time I fire the action with my watch a new activity is opened on my phone. But I want to reuse the old activity. What do I have to change?

By the way: If you have any other tips or improvements concerning my code feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve it is to declare your activity as a `singleInstance` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. You need to add `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in related activity tag.

But it really depends on what exactly do you want to achieve. Using `singleInstance` launch mode it will reorder any existing instance of this activity to the front (so it will be removed from the old place in your stack).

Tell if it's OK for your structure:)